# How to make TypeScript utility scripts within an npm TypeScript package

Tags: typescript, npm, devops, ts-node

##### Details

I'm working on a TypeScript React project, and there are some processes I'd like to automate, like creating a folder and file for a new component. I would like to create utility scripts, and I'd like for them to be in TypeScript so they will be type-safe and so any dependencies can easily be installed via npm. For readability/maintainability reasons, I'd also like to use `await` syntax, ideally at the top level.

I'm looking for a solution that does not require changing anything in `tsconfig.json`, and requires minimal changes to `package.json` (changes to `"scripts"` and `"devDependencies"` are fine), but I realize that might not be possible.

I've created an MRE, here's what my file structure looks like:

```
.
├── package.json
├── scripts
│   └── createFile.ts
├── src
│   └── components
└── tsconfig.json
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "utilscript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "create-file": "ts-node scripts/createFile.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

(With the exception of the `"include"` list, this is the base config file output by `npx tsc --init`.)

`scripts/createFile.ts`:

```
import { writeFile, mkdir } from 'node:fs/promises'

const componentName = 'Test' // will eventually be a command line argument

await mkdir(`./src/components/${componentName}`)
await writeFile(`./src/components/${componentName}/index.tsx`, '')
```

##### Errors

Attempting to run `npm run create-file` results in this TS error:

```
scripts/createFile.ts:5:1 - error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

5 await mkdir(`./src/components/${componentName}`)
  ~~~~~
scripts/createFile.ts:6:1 - error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

6 await writeFile(`./src/components/${componentName}/index.tsx`, '')
  ~~~~~
```

I then went down the rabbit hole of fixing these errors. I updated my `tsconfig.json` with `"module": "esnext"` and `"target": "es2017"`. Running `npm run create-file` resulted in this error:

```
(node:66146) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/rpmccarter/Documents/codes/misc/stackOverflow/utilScript/scripts/createFile.ts:1
import { writeFile, mkdir } from 'node:fs/promises';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I updated my `package.json` to include `"type": "module"`. Running `npm run create-file` then resulted in this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/rpmccarter/Documents/codes/misc/stackOverflow/utilScript/scripts/createFile.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new `tsconfig.json` file *within the `scripts` folder* with the following contents:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es2017",            // IMPORTANT
       "module": "esnext",            // IMPORTANT
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
       "strict": true,
       "skipLibCheck": true
     }
   }
   ```

   **NOTE**: What's important here are the `"target"` and `"module"` options. I'm only including the other options to match my base `tsconfig.json`.
2. rename utility script with the `.mts` extension **OR** add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`
3. update `package.json` script to use `ts-node --esm` (and update the file extension if you changed it):

   ```
   "create-file": "ts-node --esm scripts/createFile.mts"
   ```

Comment: `ts-node` is quite annoying to work with. Even for my scripts, I just compile them to JavaScript first using `tsc` and then run with `node`. It's a lot more explicit and doesn't rely on whatever hidden logic `ts-node` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

For a WORKAROUND, to add support for top-level await, I wrap my code in a self declare function

```
(async () => {
    await ...SOME ASYNC
})();
```

Here an example for every package.json script I use this Typescript configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2022"],
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "target": "es2022",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./",

    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```